# How to back reference an object within a mocked method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

**Method:**

```
def analyse_sentence(self, sentence, channel):
        found_top_news = 'top news' in sentence or 'trending news' in sentence
        if found_top_news:
            categories = []
            found_categories = SharedNewsUtils.extract_categories(sentence, categories)
            if found_categories:
                result = self.retrieve_top_news(categories[0])
```

**Unit test:**

```
    @patch('slack.realtime_bot.plugins.news_plugin.news.News.retrieve_top_news')
    @patch('utils.shared_news_utils.SharedNewsUtils.extract_categories')
    def test_analyse_sentence_calls_retrieve_top_news_if_found_categories(self, mck, mck2):
        mck.return_value = True
        sentence = 'trending news'
        channel = 'D'
        mck2.return_value = []
        self.news.analyse_sentence(sentence, channel)
        self.assertTrue(mck2.called)
```

This unit test fails with the message:

> ```
> result = self.retrieve_top_news(categories[0])  IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Since `extract_categories` is mocked, and an empty `categories` list is injected within the method, I don't know how to mock that as well in order to prevent the list out of index later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `extract_categories` is mutating `categories` then you should be able to use `side_effect` in  your test to mutate `categories`:

```
def mutate_categories(sentence, categories):
  categories.append('some_item')

mck.side_effect = mutate_categories
```